# SQL: delete all data from a table and all related tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a students tables & scores, classes

I want to delete all data related to students who finished their studies before 2012 - so from the students table its `delete from students where graduate year < 2012` but how do i remove all the records from the scores table? I can do a select to all id's of students before deleting them and then do a `delete from scores where studentId in []` but I bet there is a better way.

Also it doesn't solve my problem with classes since some classes are no more relevant cause their are not taken by any student and should be deleted and some still run.

Comment: Define the foreign keys as `on delete cascade`

Comment: This can be closed as "unclear" or missing an [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM scores
WHERE studentId IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM students
  WHERE graduate_year<2012
)
```

For the `DELETE from classes...` you need to provide some additional info, but the basic structure would be something like:

```
DELETE FROM classes
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT some condition that states the class is still referenced and needed)
```